# link_to with remote => true not functioning as expected

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails 3 and this is how I've set up my link_to in my view

```
<%= link_to ('add',
                :url => {:controller => 'favourite_companies', :action =>'create', 
                :company_id=>@company.id,   
                :company_name=>@company.company_name, :remote => true}) %>
```

When I click it, the page refreshes and nothing happens.

I've added <%= csrf_meta_tag %> and all javascript files.

In the controller, the function looks like this:

```
def create
  @favorite_list = 
      FavouriteCompany.new(:user_id=>curr_user.id,:company_id=>params[:company_id])
  @favorite_list.save
  render :partial => "create"
```

end

Any idea what might be wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the HTML that is being output via your browsers dev tools (ie firebug, etc)?

I believe you have the `:remote => true` in the wrong hash.

Try:

```
<%= link_to ('add',
     {:url => {:controller => 'favourite_companies', :action =>'create', 
     :company_id=>@company.id,   
     :company_name=>@company.company_name}}, :remote => true) %>
```

Is there a reason you aren't using Rails Routes and generating the link via the standard Rails process like:

```
<%= link_to 'add', favourite_companies_path(@company), :remote => true %>
```

Comment: sorry I'm a little new to this.. I am using chrome tools .. but don't know what to look for.

Comment: The trick is to get the url in the second parameter and the :remote => true in the third. Try wrapping the :url call in curly-braces. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Funny I've never used `link_to` with the `remote` option.

Whatever, it should work like all ajax calls.

So I think you should:

- remove from your controller `render :partial => "create"`
- create a view `create.js.erb`
- put your code in it such as the following:

> ```
> $('#your_container').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'create')) %>");
> ```